# How do I keep track of the total number of complete rotations of an image in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on an app that has a rotating image (the user tapps and drags and the image rotates in a circle tracking their finger). What I am trying to keep track of is how many times the user makes a complete circle. An additional "hitch" is that I also need to know if the user is circling clockwise vs counter clockwise.

Here is the Code that is rotating the image... Please feel free to request additional information.

```
   - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    long double rotationNumber = atan2(touchPoint.y - originY, touchPoint.x - originX);

    totalRotationCount ++;

    schedulingWheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationNumber);

    offset = (rotationNumber * 100)/14;

    dateRibbon.center = CGPointMake(offset, 24);  
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you interested in complete rotations only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution isn't elegant and there might be a cleaner solution I'm missing but this is what I did recently. The trick is to keep track of the angle from the last time `touchesMoved:` is called. Then, add the delta of your current angle and the stored angel value to your total.

The problem is the "boundaries" that atan2 creates needed ugly code to overcome. Say your `lastAngle` is 359 and you cross the origin so your next angle is 1. The difference will *not* be 2 but -358, so whenever you cross that boundary your total will be reset to 0.

Here is what I did:

```
 CGFloat angle = atan2f(center.y - point.y, point.x - center.x);

 //Translate to Unit circle
 if (angle > 0) {
     angle = (M_PI - angle) + M_PI;
 } else {
     angle = fabsf(angle);
 }

 CGFloat delta = angle - lastAngle;

 //Adjust for boundaries
 if (fabsf(delta) > (2*M_PI)-fabsf(delta)) {
      BOOL greaterThanZero = (delta > 0);
      delta = (2*M_PI)-fabsf(delta);
      if (greaterThanZero) {
           delta = -1 * delta;
      }
  }

  totalAngle += delta;
  lastAngle = angle;
```

The big/ugly conditional under "Adjust for boundaries" basically just looks to see if there is a shorter angle to get to the new point (So, 2 instead of -258) & assumes that if there is it probably means you crossed that origin and adjusts the delta accordingly.

I translated the Atan2 results so that it represents a full unit circle from 0 to 2π. Bonus side affect, it then accounts for clockwise/counter clockwise movement better than the standard -π to π of Atan2.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what is the total number of the rotations simply sum all the rotation angles in either directions. For clockwise the value of the rotation angle will be positive and for the counter clockwise it will be negative. Then divide it by a pi (~3.14) to get your total number of rotations.

```
long double rotationNumber = atan2(touchPoint.y - originY, touchPoint.x - originX);
long double totalRotationsAngle += rotationNumber;
```

Then whenever you want to get the number of full rotations:

```
double numberOfRotations = floor(totalRotationsAngle/M_PI);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Atan2 doesn't give a +/- value based on counter/clockwise direction. It gives a value between {-pi, pi} (Positive for upper half of the unit circle, negative for lower). Furthermore, by always adding the full angle you just taking something closer to the factorial of the actual angle rotated (thought not exactly because the event wouldn't fire every degree).